# Is there a diagnostic tool when there is no event log report for a crash?

Tags: windows-10

I have an old music notation program called Encore 5 used to make sheet music, and I'm trying to open the associated .enc files I have.

My problem is the following: if I directly open .enc files, Encore 5 opens and closes instantly. If I instead first open Encore 5, use the file browser by using the File -> Open... button inside Encore 5, and then open the file, everything works fine.

I haven't been able to find anything about this problem specifically with Encore 5 online, but I'd like to fix it. Is there any tool I can use to begin diagnosing why directly opening an .enc file opens and closes? Nothing gets outputted to the Event Log when this happens.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Enable minidumps in Advanced System Properties, restart and next crash get the Mini Dump and edit your answer to post the dump. You can get Nirsoft Blue Screen View to look at it.

Comment: @John thank you very much!

Comment: Program crashes don't generate dump files, only system crashes do. See tutorial here on using WinDbg (Windows Debugger). This will give you the error code. But it sounds like your program is choosing to exit, possibly because it can't find a file. Type in a cmd prompt `assoc .enc` and whatever it is equal `ftype encfile` (eg for notepad `assoc .txt` and that is equal to `textfile` so `ftype txtfile` and paste the results.

Comment: @user1292580 I noticed that some time after beginning to mess around with the dump files. Thanks a lot for the help!